# Reactive sub-form group inside bootstrap modal

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form, one of its part is inside `ngFor` so when ever I click on a button inside that `ngFor` i need to popup a modal and show some fields inside my modal.

my parent component : `order-create.component.ts`

```
export class OrderCreateComponent {

    @ViewChild(AlterationComponent) alteration: AlterationComponent;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

    createForm() {

    this.orderForm = this.fb.group({
      customer_name: ['', Validators.required],
      customer_badge: ['', Validators.required],      
      items: this.fb.array([ ])
    });

    let items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;

    this.suit_items.forEach(obj => {
      items.push(this.createItemForm(obj));
    });

  }

  createItemForm(obj): FormGroup {

    return this.fb.group({
      suit_item_id: [obj.id, Validators.required],
      alteration: this.fb.group({
        length: ''
      })
    });

  }
   openAlterationModal(item) {
    this.alteration.openModal(item.get('alteration'));
  }

}
```

`create-order.html`

```
<form [formGroup]="orderForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">
......
<div *ngFor="let item of orderForm.get('items').controls; let i = index;"">
    ......
    <button (click)="openAlterationModal(item)">open modal</button>
</div>
 <app-alteration></app-alteration>
</form>
```

`alteration.component.ts`

```
@Component ({
  selector: 'app-alteration',
  templateUrl: 'alteration.html'
})

export class AlterationComponent {
  alterationForm: FormGroup;
  openModal(alteration: FormGroup) {
    this.alterationForm = alteration;
  }

}
```

`alteration.html`

```
.....
<div [formGroup]="alterationForm" *ngIf="alterationForm">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="length" name="length" placeholder="length" formControlName="length" required>
</div>
.....
```

My problem is my formgroup inside my modal=>alteration.html is not showing, but I can console that form group in my `alteration.component.ts` openModal function.

I don't know whether I am doing it in right way. I am new to angular. What should I do.

Comment: Could you please add a stackblitz for us to replicate the issue? It is not mandatory, but if you could do that, it helps a lot.

Comment: Created stackblitz with minimum requirements but it is working
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pboqks

Comment: is the stack-blitz working as per your requirement? Is that what you meant?